# transferring data from an array to a combo box in vb6

Tags: arrays, vb6

here's the case 
on clicking anyone of the three check boxes i need the data to flow from an array to the combo box i tried creating an array but m not sure if its the right way hers the code:

```
Private B(2) As String
Private M(2) As String
Private P(2) As String

Private Sub Combo1_Change(Index As Integer)
Dim B As String
Dim M As String
Dim P As String
B = Array("Bicholim", "Valpoi")
M = Array("Mapusa", "Pernem", "Porvorim")
P = Array("Panjim", "Ponda")

If Check1.Checked = True Then
Combo1.items.Add (Bicholim)
Else 
combo1.item = Null

If Check2.Checked = True Then
Combo1.items.Add (M)
Else
Combo1.Item = Null

If Check3.Checked = True Then
Combo1.items.Add (P)
Else
Combo1.Item = Null
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing your `End If` at the end of each of your `If` statements.  Do you get an error?

Answer (score 3):

Quick code review:

First of all, what a mess. You have VB6 control array event procedures [Private Sub Combo1_Change(Index As Integer)] and default named controls [Combo1, Check1, Check2, Check3]. However, the combo add item syntax is VB.NET [Combo1.items.Add()].

**Syntactically:**

- The *End If* statement has been left off each *If/Then* block. Sounds as
  if you are a C# programmer.
- *Bicholim* is being used as a constant,
  when you probably mean "Bicholim".
- You have declared *B*, *M* and *P* at
  module level AND at procedure level. The latter take priority over
  the module level variables.
- The procedure level variables *B*, *M* and *P*
  are declared *As String*. However, the *Array* function returns a *Variant*
  of type *String()*.

**Standard VB6 objects:**

- The checkboxes are using the wrong property. Instead of using the *Checked*
  property, you should be using *Value*, which uses the values:
  *vbChecked*, *vbUnchecked*, and *vbGrayed*.
- The combo box reference is being used as a standard object *Combo1*, but the event procedure says it is part of a control array *(Index As Integer)*. I would
  remove the control array parameter.
- *Combo1.Items.Add*(<whatever>) is being used to add items to the combo box. It should be: *Combo1.AddItem(<whatever>)*.
- *Combo1.Items.Add* is being used to add a
  string array. You can't do this in VB6 (in any case, .NET would use
  *AddRange()*).
- *Combo1.Item* = Null is being used ... for what?. Even
  the .NET WinForm checkbox doesn't use this syntax.

I am guessing that you basically want different items in the combo box, depending on the state of the checkboxes. I don't know why you want to use the *Combo1 Change* event. It sounds unlikely. Instead, you would want to respond to a checkbox click. So the code you provided should be in a procedure, called from each check box *Click* event procedure.

Let's fix this up so far:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub RefreshCombo()
    Dim B As Variant
    Dim M As Variant
    Dim P As Variant
    B = Array("Bicholim", "Valpoi")
    M = Array("Mapusa", "Pernem", "Porvorim")
    P = Array("Panjim", "Ponda")

    ' Remove all items from the array.
    Combo1.Clear

    If Check1.Value = vbChecked Then
        AddArrayItemsToComboBox Combo1, B
    End If

    If Check2.Value = vbChecked Then
        AddArrayItemsToComboBox Combo1, M
    End If

    If Check3.Value = vbChecked Then
        AddArrayItemsToComboBox Combo1, P
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddArrayItemsToComboBox(ByRef cmb As ComboBox, ByRef vasValues As Variant)

    Dim nIndex As Long

    For nIndex = 0 To UBound(vasValues)
        Combo1.AddItem vasValues(nIndex)
    Next nIndex

End Sub

Private Sub Check1_Click()
    RefreshCombo
End Sub

Private Sub Check2_Click()
    RefreshCombo
End Sub

Private Sub Check3_Click()
    RefreshCombo
End Sub
```

You could neaten this up by using a control array of check boxes.